# Write (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) as a product of 3-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

It's not necessarily disjoint. I know how to work the other way around but get stuck trying to do this process.

Comment: Write it as a product of $2$-cycles, then pair off them to make $3$-cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 4\ 5)(1\ 6\ 7) $

Answer (score 0):

$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)=(1\ 2\ 3)(3\ 4\ 5)(5\ 6\ 7)$